# Why [:2] doesn't work for numbers less than 10 in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function in python that takes in a txt file of the form:
[image]

And my json file which is the result is the following [image]

So what I want to know is:

1) why in numbers of 2 digits and above the \n character is gone and in numbers of 1 digit the character \n remains there. Is there any solution to that? Keep in mind that I want all new line characters to be removed.

2) why I get a warning that my line variable is unused ( I have commented in the start of the code where it occurs). Although I think it is doing what it is supposed to do.

Here is my code

```
def create_dict_from_index_txt(file_name):

# Create a dynamical dictionary from the input file
num_of_lines = 0
words = []

# find how many lines there are in the files
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    for line in f: # I get a warning that line is unused
        num_of_lines += 1
print("Number of lines: ", num_of_lines)
f.close()

f1 = open(file_name, 'r')
# find how many arguments each line has
for i in range(num_of_lines):
    words_per_line = f1.readline().split(" ")
    words.append(len(words_per_line))
print("Number of columns per line: ", words)

# Initialize the saving space of lines I want
a = [0] * num_of_lines
# Initialize the saving space of columns in each line
for i in range(num_of_lines):
    a[i] = [0] * words[i]
print("Initialized a: ", a)
f1.close()

f1 = open(file_name, 'r')
# Getting the info from each line and fill in the a 2d list
for i in range(num_of_lines):
    ln = f1.readline().split(" ")
    for j in range(words[i]):
        a[i][j] = ln[j]
print("First tokenize of index.txt: ", a)
f1.close()

# Delete the new line delimiter parsing only the last element of each row
for i in range(num_of_lines):
    inner_index = words[i]-1
    tok = a[i][inner_index]
    if "\n" in tok:
        a[i][inner_index] = a[i][inner_index][:2] # <------ HERE IS THE [:2]
print("Attempt to delete new lines", a)

# Initialize the saving space for keys and Extract only the keys of the 2d list (a)
keys = [0] * num_of_lines
for i in range(num_of_lines):
    keys[i] = a[i][0]
print("The keys are: ", keys)

# Initialize the saving space for the ids
ids = [0] * num_of_lines
for i in range(num_of_lines):
        ids[i] = [0] * (words[i]-1)
print("Initialized ids: ", ids)

# extract the ids of the 2d list (a)
for i in range(num_of_lines):
    for j in range(1, words[i]):
        ids[i][j-1] = a[i][j]

print("Only ids of each word: ", ids)

dictionary = {}
# create a dictionary dynamically
for i in range(num_of_lines):
    dictionary.update({keys[i]: ids[i]})

print("The final dictionary of the input text file is: ", dictionary)
# End of creating a dynamical dictionary

return dictionary
```

Keep in mind that I am new in Python and I am still learning the basics.

Comment: Well 1) what did you expect from e.g. `"1\n"[:2]` vs. `"10\n[:2]"`? You asked for two characters... and 2) you get a warning that line is unused, because... it isn't used. There's only one statement in the for block, and it doesn't refer to line. Also please don't put pictures of text content, present it as code block formatted text, and ask a single question at a time with a [mcve].

Comment: well my code is complete and I asked for one main thing and a simple explanation you don't have to be harsh for nothing. From "1\n" the [:2] leaves the newline character as it is but in "10\n" it removes the newline character this is what I am asking. Also I don't really see the point in down voting a question for nothing

Comment: @GerasimosRagavanis: posting images is poorly received here because we are used to copy-paste code and input data. That alone is enough to deserve down votes. And jonrsharpe's comment are not harsh but questions you about questionable code. For the question, the correct way to remove the last char from a string is `newstr = oldstr[:-1]` and the correct way to remove an end of line is `newline = rstrip(oldline)`. But you whole code is not Pythonic...

Comment: Thank you for your answer I get it now. It was too complicated and not memory-friendly

Comment: You're asking why the first two characters of a two digit number are different to the first two characters of a one digit number, at which point it's hard to understand what your question is. Also you've skipped over the *minimal* part. I'd recommend reviewing [ask].

Comment: I thought :2 means the last 2 characters. And for example 2: is the first two characters. Obviously I am wrong. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you are new in Python but you are taking it the wrong side. The default sequence and mapping class in Python are dynamic list and can be appended to. So the Pythonic way here is to:

- initialize an empty dictionary
- read the file, one line at a time, strip the end of line, and tokenize it

  - first word is the key
  - remaining words are the ids
  - add the processed line to the dictionary

So code can be as simple as:

```
dictionary = {}
with open(file_name, 'r') as f1:      # with ensure that the file will be close at end of block
    for line in f1:
        words = line.strip().split()  # trim white spaces (including end of lines from both ends
                                      # split on spaces
        dictionary[words[0]] = words[1:]  # add to final dictionnary

print dictionary                      # control correct processing
```